# Rewarded ads worked fine in my Unity app. Why are they failing to load now?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ads

Rewarded ads were working fine for a long while until perhaps a few months ago and now I'm finally addressing this issue. I'm getting the following error message:

Error loading Ad Unit Rewarded_iOS: INVALID_ARGUMENT - Placement Rewarded_iOS does not exist for gameId: [I've deleted the gameId from display in this Unity forum for my own security, but I have the correct numbers for Android and of iOS.]
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
ViewAdGainFreeHints:OnUnityAdsFailedToLoad (string,UnityEngine.Advertisements.UnityAdsLoadError,string) (at Assets/Scripts/ViewAdGainFreeHints.cs:101)
UnityEngine.Advertisements.Utilities.CoroutineExecutor:Update () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ads@4.4.2/Runtime/Advertisement/Utilities/CoroutineExecutor.cs:17)

My ads package is up-to-date (4.4.2).

My Unity Gaming Services dashboard looks fine.

My entire ViewAdGainFreeHints.cs is below.

Please help. Thank you.

```
> using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class ViewAdGainFreeHints : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsLoadListener, IUnityAdsShowListener
{
    [SerializeField] Button _showAdButton;
    [SerializeField] string _androidAdUnitId = "Rewarded_Android";
    [SerializeField] string _iOSAdUnitId = "Rewarded_iOS";
    string _adUnitId = null; // This will remain null for unsupported platforms


    
    int hintsForViewingAd = 10; // Reward for viewing an ad.

    public GameOverScreen gameOverScreen;

    void Awake()
    {
        // Get the Ad Unit ID for the current platform:
#if UNITY_IOS
        _adUnitId = _iOSAdUnitId;
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        _adUnitId = _androidAdUnitId;
#elif UNITY_EDITOR_OSX || UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX
        _adUnitId = _androidAdUnitId;
#endif

        ////Disable the button until the ad is ready to show:
        //_showAdButton.interactable = false;
    }

    // Load content to the Ad Unit:
    public void LoadAd()
{
    // IMPORTANT! Only load content AFTER initialization (in this example, initialization is handled in a different script).
    Debug.Log("Loading Ad: " + _adUnitId);
    Advertisement.Load(_adUnitId, this);
}

// If the ad successfully loads, add a listener to the button and enable it:
public void OnUnityAdsAdLoaded(string adUnitId)
{
    Debug.Log("Ad Loaded: " + adUnitId);

    if (adUnitId.Equals(_adUnitId))
    {
        // Configure the button to call the ShowAd() method when clicked:
        _showAdButton.onClick.AddListener(ShowAd);
        // Enable the button for users to click:
        _showAdButton.interactable = true;
    }
}

// Implement a method to execute when the user clicks the button:
public void ShowAd()
{
    // Disable the button:
    _showAdButton.interactable = false;
    // Then show the ad:
    Advertisement.Show(_adUnitId, this);
}

// Implement the Show Listener's OnUnityAdsShowComplete callback method to determine if the user gets a reward:
public void OnUnityAdsShowComplete(string adUnitId, UnityAdsShowCompletionState showCompletionState)
{
    if (adUnitId.Equals(_adUnitId) && showCompletionState.Equals(UnityAdsShowCompletionState.COMPLETED))
    {
        Debug.Log("Unity Ads Rewarded Ad Completed");
            // Issue reward:
            int numberOfHintsRemaining = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HintsRemainingCount");

            Debug.Log("numberOfHintsRemaining = " + numberOfHintsRemaining); // 11 June 2022

            numberOfHintsRemaining = numberOfHintsRemaining + hintsForViewingAd;

            Debug.Log("numberOfHintsRemaining = " + numberOfHintsRemaining); // 11 June 2022

            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HintsRemainingCount", numberOfHintsRemaining);

            Debug.Log("HintsRemainingCount = " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HintsRemainingCount")); // 11 June 2022

            Debug.Log("numberOfHintsRemaining = " + numberOfHintsRemaining); // 11 June 2022

            PlayerPrefs.Save();
            gameOverScreen.NumberOfHintsRemainingText.text = numberOfHintsRemaining.ToString();

            Debug.Log("You have received " + hintsForViewingAd + " hints for viewing an ad!");

        // Load another ad:
        Advertisement.Load(_adUnitId, this); 

    }

        _showAdButton.onClick.RemoveListener(ShowAd);
}

    // Implement Load and Show Listener error callbacks:
    public void OnUnityAdsFailedToLoad(string adUnitId, UnityAdsLoadError error, string message)
{
    Debug.Log($"Error loading Ad Unit {adUnitId}: {error.ToString()} - {message}");
    // Use the error details to determine whether to try to load another ad.
}

public void OnUnityAdsShowFailure(string adUnitId, UnityAdsShowError error, string message)
{
    Debug.Log($"Error showing Ad Unit {adUnitId}: {error.ToString()} - {message}");
    // Use the error details to determine whether to try to load another ad.
}

public void OnUnityAdsShowStart(string adUnitId) { }
public void OnUnityAdsShowClick(string adUnitId) { }

void OnDestroy()
{
    // Clean up the button listeners:
    _showAdButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();}}
```

Comment: Do you have Rewarded_iOS placement in Unity Ads ? Seems like you don't created  this placement for this specific game Id.

Comment: @Jaimin Thanks for your response. I've already gone ahead and tried migrating to Unity LevelPlay as Ads Mediation recommended to me. If I can install that properly, I'll see if the rewarded ads load properly.